# Why Android FragmentStateAdapter failed onActivityResult?

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, adapter, onactivityresult

For example: in activity 1 i have 2 tabs named workers_list tab and notes tab. when any workers_list item is selected then new activity is opened to view & update details about that worker.

**Expected output:**

[image: This is what i expected]

Comment: @AlexMamo My adapter is not updating the list whenever i select and modify the item from my fragment in second activity. How do i update fragment at position 1?

Comment: if your worker list is RecyclerView, then try to use adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: @Spectator not working

Comment: can you share the code when user trying to update profile?

Comment: @Spectator there is no problem in updating of list. It works fine when i completely reopen my Activity 1 then only list is updated.

Comment: did you try to debug?(if yes, what that shows?) is your “if” working in onActivityResult?

Comment: yes my if is matched

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. Just called `activityResultLauncher.launch(intent);` from inside the adapter instead of `startActivity(intent);`

Thank myself